# Using Vue multiselect to change Algolia index

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I currently have a page where I'm able to switch Algolia indices with this:

```
<template>
    <button @click="selectedIndex = a">List A</button>
    <button @click="selectedIndex = b">List B</button>

    <A v-if="selectedIndex === a" />
    <B v-if="selectedIndex === b" />
</template>

<script>
import A from '@/A.vue';
import B from '@/B.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        A,
        B
    },

    data() {
        return {
            selectedIndex: `a_${this.$root.index}`,
            query: ''
        };
    },

    computed: {
        a() {
            return `a_${this.$root.index}`;
        },

        b() {
            return `b_${this.$root.index}`;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

This is in a file called `Index.vue`. The different indices are in files `A.vue` and `B.vue`.

But now I need to be able to do the same content switching using a `vue-multiselect` in `A.vue` and `B.vue`.

Currently in `A.vue`, I have

```
<template>
    <ais-instant-search
        :search-client="searchClient"
        :index-name="a"
        :routing="routing"
    >
    <multiselect
        v-model="selectedIndex"
        :options="switcherOptions"
        :searchable="false"
        :close-on-select="true"
        :show-labels="false"
        placeholder="Choose"
    >
        <template slot="singleLabel" slot-scope="{ option }">
            {{ option.text }}
        </template>
        <template slot="option" slot-scope="{ option }">
            {{ option.text }}
        </template>
    </multiselect>
    </ais-instant-search>
</template>    

export default {
    components: {
        Multiselect
    },

    data() {
            searchClient: algoliasearch(window.algolia.id, window.algolia.key),
            selectedIndex: { value: 'a', text: 'List A' },
            switcherOptions: [
                { value: 'a', text: 'List A' },
                { value: 'b', text: 'List B' }
            ]
        };
    },
};
```

What I don't know how to do now is send the value from the `multi-select` from `A.vue` back up to `Index.vue` where the different indices are defined.

Answer (score 0):

First observation that I have, in your `A.vue` you are binding variable named `a` to your index, but do not have `a` defined in your data, same thing for `routing`.

What is the point of computed properties `a` and `b`, they are just returning strings, with do not do any computing, this could probably be defined in `data`:

```
    data() {
        return {
            selectedIndex: 'a_index',
            query: '',
            a: 'a_index',
            b: 'b_index',
        };
    },
```

Are `A.vue` and `B.vue` identical components? If only bindings are different, you can probably combine them into one component, and just pass different props to them. Hard to know for sure without seeing complete code.

So one way of doing this is emitting events from child to parent components. Documentation reference: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html

On your multiselect component add `@select="$emit("indexSelected", selectedIndex)"`

Like so:

```
<multiselect
        v-model="selectedIndex"
        :options="switcherOptions"
        :searchable="false"
        :close-on-select="true"
        :show-labels="false"
        placeholder="Choose"
        @select="$emit("indexSelected", selectedIndex)"
    >
```

This will emit event with name of `indexSelected` and included `selectedIndex` value in its payload.

Then in `Index.vue` you need to add these event listeners to both A and B Components:

```
    <A v-if="selectedIndex === a" @indexSelected="selectedIndex = $event.value === 'a' ? 'a_index' : 'b_index'" />
    <B v-if="selectedIndex === b" @indexSelected="selectedIndex = $event.value === 'a' ? 'a_index' : 'b_index'" />
```

Or if you would like cleaner template you can create a method:

```
methods: {
  updateSelectedIndex(event){
    this.selectedIndex = event.value === 'a' ? 'a_index' : 'b_index';
  }
}
```

And then update template to:

```
    <A v-if="selectedIndex === a" @indexSelected="updateSelectedIndex" />
    <B v-if="selectedIndex === b" @indexSelected="updateSelectedIndex" />
```

**EDIT:**

I think this is kind of what you are looking for(reading between the lines lol), this rolls `Index.vue`, `A.vue`, `B.vue` into one component, because what you are trying to achieve is a lot simpler this way IMO. Obviously your actual app is more complex, so apply this as needed.

`IndexAB.vue` would look like this, values replaces with algolia demo, so substitute as needed:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>
      <strong>Changing Index with buttons: </strong>
      <button
        v-for="option in searchIndexOptions"
        :key="option.value"
        @click="searchIndexName = option"
      >
        {{ option.text }}
      </button>
    </p>
    <ais-instant-search
      :search-client="searchClient"
      :index-name="searchIndexName.value"
    >
      <p>
        <strong>Changing Index with vue-multiselect: </strong>

        <VueMultiselect
          v-model="searchIndexName"
          :options="searchIndexOptions"
          :searchable="false"
          :close-on-select="true"
          track-by="value"
          label="text"
          placeholder="Change Search Index Here"
        >
          <template v-slot:singleLabel="{ option }">
            <strong>{{ option.text }}</strong>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:option="{ option }">
            <strong>{{ option.text }}</strong>
          </template>
        </VueMultiselect>
      </p>
      <ais-search-box />
      <ais-hits>
        <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
          <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
        </template>
      </ais-hits>
    </ais-instant-search>
  </div>
</template>    

<script>
import VueMultiselect from "vue-multiselect";
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";
import "instantsearch.css/themes/satellite-min.css";
import "vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.css";

export default {
  name: "IndexAB",
  components: { VueMultiselect },
  data: () => ({
    searchClient: algoliasearch("latency", "6be0576ff61c053d5f9a3225e2a90f76"),
    searchIndexName: { value: "instant_search", text: "List A" }, // Defaults to instant_search/List A
    searchIndexOptions: [
      { value: "instant_search", text: "List A" },
      { value: "airbnb", text: "List B" },
      { value: "airports", text: "List C" },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>
```

And sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-ptolemy-9ljmhh?file=/src/components/IndexAB.vue

I had started with Vue 3 sandbox, so few things will be sligtly different(like import of vue-multiselect, and v-slot syntax)

Comment: I've edited my answer. I tried reducing the code a bit to make it easier to read but reduced it too much. `a` and `b` are functions because they're actually taking a value from a data-attribute set on the HTML file that's pulling in all the Vue stuff.
So I've tried adding `@indexSelected="selectedIndex = $event.value"` to the two components but on change I get nothing.
And the reason they're two separate components is because they're displaying  results from two different Algolia indices.

Comment: I’m on mobile now, will re read your question in the morning. But as far as A and B. Just pass the algolia index as prop from Index.vue. Something like this: `<A :index=selectedIndex” />`https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#static-vs-dynamic-props

Comment: @Tyssen Answer updated, let me know if I'm close to what you are trying to achive :)

Comment: Thanks, that's a really nice solution, but as you mentioned, my app is a bit more complex. Each of the indexes actually pulls in a different component for the `ais-hits` and has slightly different searching tools too which is why they're separated into different components. So I think I still need a wait for the value of the `multiselect` to emit back up to the parent.